# JavaScript calling a method on an object syntax

Tags: javascript, object, methods

I am a beginner in JavaScript and I am reading JavaScript for Kids by Nick Morgan.

I created the following function in JavaScript -

```
var speak = function () {
    console.log(this.sound + "! My name is", this.name + "!");
};
```

and I also created this object of a cat on which I want to use this function as a method -

```
var cat = {
    sound: "Miaow",
    name: "Mittens",
    speak: speak
};
```

Now, I'm slightly confused here.
`cat.speak` I know refers to a method.

If I call `cat.speak`, I know that I am accessing the value of the speak property and hence it returns the function definition

```
function () {
    console.log(this.sound + "! My name is", this.name + "!");
}
```

but I don't understand from where I am accessing `cat.speak()`.

What is the difference between the two statements that I have called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this example can help you:

```
var speak = function () {
    console.log(this.sound + "! My name is", this.name + "!");
};

var cat = {
    sound: "Miaow",
    name: "Mittens",
    speak: speak
};


console.log(cat.speak);
cat.speak();
```

When you call cat.speak() the function assigned to the var speak is called on the object.
Instead if you call cat.speak you get the function definition.